# eclipse autocomplete iterator for C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete, iterator

Here is my code (Which compiles fine):

```
auto_ptr<people_t> ppl(people("people.xml"));
people_t::person_sequence &ps(ppl->person());
for(people_t::person_iterator i (ps.begin()); i!=ps.end(); ++i)
```

In the last line, when I try to choose `begin()` and `end()` from a list of auto-complete list, the only thing i get is "sequence" (not `begin, end`...) so I have to type them. Any Idea why? and how to solve this issue?

Comment: @rahman: Which version of eclipse and CDT do you use?

Comment: @@ Björn Pollex:not sure about the CDT(don't know where to find it :) ) but eclipse is Version: 3.7.0. I installed it through apt-get less than a month ago.

Comment: Is `people` a class ? Then what is `people_t` ? I am not sure how it compiles. If you have access to c++11 compiler and allowed to use it, please use `unique_ptr` instead of `auto_ptr`. `auto_ptr` is deprecated now in the new standard. Please provide more information about the classes. That could help in understanding the problem.

Comment: [This is not an answer.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly why those two symbols don't show up in the list. However, C++ has one of the most complex grammars of any programming language out there. Generally for tools that don't have to understand all of it (compilers), they try to do a reasonably good job with most of it (80/20 rule). So when you get into heavy macro and template use especially, the IDE is probably going to get confused.

One thing I noticed is that because of this, I actually am much more confident in my knowledge of C++ than of Java. So there are tradeoffs. If you know it's right and the compiler doesn't complain, I wouldn't worry about it.

Comment: @@parkovski, thanks. you are probabely right. thats what i also had guessed. I will give it a while and if no other answer was given, I will mark your answer as true. tanx

Comment: I have had a number of issues in template and macros with Eclipse, so it would not surprise me at all. Their strategy of reimplementing a C++ parser shows its shortcomings here :x